# How to import jar file to scene builder with css file? ( css file does't apply )

Tags: javafx, jar, scenebuilder

I have developing custom button control. Code is very simple. I just create MyButton class extend Button class. And I adding css that in same file. like this

```
public class PrimaryButton extends Button {
public PrimaryButton(){
    getStyleClass().add("primary-button");
    getStylesheets().add("primarybutton.css");
   }
}
```

My project structure is [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZ6Do.jpg)

I made this project file to jar. And I import this jar to scene builder. But css dose not apply. [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GSkF7.jpg). What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with in your CSS file path, and when i changed it,into

```
getStylesheets().add("sample/primarybutton.css");
```

it worked fine, and this also worked fine

```
getStylesheets().add("/sample/primarybutton.css");
```

> NOTE: my app architecture is completely identical to yours

here's the complete sample

```
public class MyButton extends Button {
public MyButton(){
    getStylesheets().add("sample/primarybutton.css");
    //you can also use this
    //getStylesheets().add("/sample/primarybutton.css");
    getStyleClass().add("primary-button");
} }
```

> Note : the "primary-button" is a css class in your "primarybutton.css" file

hope this is useful, and solve your problem

Comment: Thanks your answer. But I tried that way, I couldn't solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

The string you pass to the list of stylesheets is treated as a URL. The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets--) states:

> The URL is a hierarchical URI of the form [scheme:][//authority][path]. 
>   If the URL does not have a [scheme:] component, the URL is considered
>   to be the [path] component only. Any leading '/' character of the
>   [path] is ignored and the [path] is treated as a path relative to the
>   root of the application's classpath.

Since both the class and the stylesheet are in the `sample` package, the URL of the stylesheet relative to the classpath is `sample/primarybutton.css`, so you could use

```
getStylesheets().add("sample/primarybutton.css");
```

If you want to make use of the fact the the stylesheet is in the same package as the class, and make the code more portable (i.e. not hard-code the package name), you can create a complete URL from the current class, and then convert it to a string:

```
getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("primarybutton.css").toExternalForm());
```

This works because `getClass().getResource(...)` creates a URL where the resource name, if it doesn't begin with a leading `/`, is interpreted as being relative to the current class.

I generally prefer the latter approach, though others may not agree.

Comment: what is 'toExternalForm() ' mean?

Comment: It converts the URL to an external form, i.e. to a form that doesn't depend on the context.